# Update submodules, some tracking branches, some not tracking branches, with --remote argument

Tags: git, git-submodules

Is there a way to do something like:

`git submodule update --remote`

On a repository that contains multiple submodules that do not track branches ? I just want the one that actually do track branches to update and the other ones to do nothing (or update to the sha1 targeted as usual).
Right now I get this error when git tries to update a submodule that does not track anything:

```
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path 'modules/mod4'
```

I guess the "--remote" argument causes git to try to checkout a branch but something goes wrong there since there is no "branch" set in my .gitmodule entry.
I'm about to throw a bunch of scripts at my issue but maybe there is an elegant solution just with git that I don't see ?

Here is an output example:

```
> git submodule update --remote --force
Submodule path 'modules/mod1': checked out 'bebbe6721007f06765ec1cd7cb9f1bf6ac654c33'
Submodule path 'modules/mod2': checked out '3b4c9dadfa432fd6fdd400695770f6cb50f7fb17'
Submodule path 'modules/mod3': checked out 'c619954bad6673abd44eac520d43b448168ca196'
Submodule path 'modules/mod5': checked out '5f64331aab836218a86fc3640f91ab029b4e1890'
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path 'modules/mod4'
```

and my .gitmodules for reference:

```
[submodule "modules/mod1"]
    path = modules/mod1
    url = ssh://git@stash.sd.repo.com/mod1.git
    branch = develop
[submodule "modules/mod2"]
    path = modules/mod2
    url = ssh://git@stash.sd.repo.com/mod2.git
    branch = develop
[submodule "modules/mod3"]
    path = modules/mod3
    url = ssh://git@stash.sd.repo.com/mod3.git
    branch = develop
[submodule "modules/mod4"]
    path = modules/mod4
    url = ssh://git@stash.sd.repo.com/mod4.git
[submodule "modules/mod5"]
    path = modules/mod5
    url = ssh://git@stash.sd.repo.com/mod5.git
    branch = develop
[submodule "modules/mod6"]
    path = modules/mod6
    url = ssh://git@stash.sd.repo.com/mod6.git
    branch = develop
[submodule "modules/mod7"]
    path = modules/mod7
    url = ssh://git@stash.sd.repo.com/mod7.git
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The `--remote` option simply directs `git submodule update` to do its action *after* running `git fetch` in the submodule, *using* some remote-tracking name:

> `--remote`
> This option is only valid for the update command. Instead of using
> the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the submodule, use the
> status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch. The remote used
> is branch’s remote (`branch.<name>.remote`), defaulting to `origin`.
> **The remote branch used defaults to `master`,** but the branch name may
> be overridden by setting the `submodule.<name>.branch` option in
> either `.gitmodules` or `.git/config` (with `.git/config` taking
> precedence).
>
> ...
>
> In order to ensure a current tracking branch state, `update --remote` [**runs `git fetch` in the submodule**].

There is more; read [the `git submodule` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) carefully.  Note the parts I put in bold above though.

This means your problem isn't necessarily the branch setting, or lack thereof: the `git submodule update` command defaults to `master`.

Hence, this:

> ```
> fatal: Needed a single revision
> Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path 'modules/mod4'
> ```

means that after running `git fetch`, there was no `origin/master`.

We don't know anything more than that.  You, however, can find out more.  Perhaps there was an updated `origin/main` for instance: perhaps whoever was in charge of this particular repository renamed `master` to `main`.  If so, all superprojects that refer to this submodule should probably add a branch directive, so that the default `master` gets overridden.

Assuming that you have control over your superproject, you can do this yourself.  If not, you can use the `.git/config` trick: see the "taking precedence" parenthetical remark.

Comment: The issue I have with adding a branch directive to the submodule that do not have one is that running "git submodule update --remote" will pull the top of the branch for every submodule. I need to have some submodule to not do that and stick to the SHA1 they point to.

Comment: With `--remote`, they *don't*. They move to the commit hash ID selected by `origin/master` or whatever name. What you're seeing, when the commit hash ID sticks around, is simply that the name—`origin/master` or whatever—still **maps to the same hash ID**.